# Feedback problems

Tags: audio-feedback

bit of an awkward one. I have a American special strat and black star ht5r. Basically the spring that adjusts the pickup height (humbucker in the bridge) fell out so I had a huge ordeal fixing that because it magnetised to the humbucker inside etc... But now when I play I get a terrible high pitch feedback sound. Turning the volume down doesn't make a difference and I don't have a noise gate, this never happened before... Please help :)

Comment: Is it feedback? There are two possibilities - you are getting acoustic feedback through however you fixed the pickup mount, or you broke something.

Comment: Please add some more info – pictures, some recording of the sound, test configuration...

Answer (score 1):

OK, you need to take the pick guard off and get that spring out.  You need to get it off the humbucker's magnets and back onto the screw-height post that it's supposed to be on.  The spring is probably causing a short in the wiring between the coils of the humbucker and that's why you are getting the high-pitched sound.